# How to set iterm trigger?

Tags: iterm2

I found [iterm2-zmodem](https://github.com/mmastrac/iterm2-zmodem) and wonder how to set trigger for iterm2?

> Installation and configuration
>
> The script iterm2-zmodem should by copied to /usr/local/bin.
>
> It's required to setup the following "Triggers" in iTerm2:

```
Regular expression: \*\*B0100
Action:             Run Coprocess
Parameters:         /usr/local/bin/iterm2-zmodem sz

Regular expression: \*\*B00000000000000
Action:             Run Coprocess
Parameters:         /usr/local/bin/iterm2-zmodem rz
```

Comment: Found it. At Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced